# Draggable images on 3D surface

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating 3D program in WPF in C#. I'd like to move images which are place on  3D surface.
In my case they're situated on square. The problem is when I  try to move the image, other
 images change their sizes. 
I tried setting contstraints but it seems that the problem is that images and canvas are placed in 3D.

Does anybod have an idea how to get rid of this problem ?

Part of wpf code:

```
    <Viewport2DVisual3D
  Material="{StaticResource visualHostMaterial}" 
  Geometry="{StaticResource squareMeshFrontRight}">
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ImageHolder"  >
            <Image Canvas.Left="36" MouseWheel="Img_MouseWheel" MouseMove="Img_MouseMove" 
           MouseDown="Img_MouseDown" MouseUp="Img_MouseUp" Panel.ZIndex="0" 
           Cursor="Hand" Canvas.Top="33" Height="150" Width="150" Source="sketch.jpg" 
           x:Name="Img" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="60" MaxWidth="60" MaxHeight="60">
            </Image>
            <Image Canvas.Left="341" MouseWheel="Img_MouseWheel" MouseMove="Img_MouseMove" 
           MouseDown="Img_MouseDown" MouseUp="Img_MouseUp" Panel.ZIndex="0" 
           Cursor="Hand" Canvas.Top="22" Height="72" Width="77" Source="GreenSquare.jpg" 
           x:Name="Img2">
            </Image>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

Methods used for moving imgaes:

```
    Point p;
    Image tmpImg;

    private void Img_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tmpImg = sender as Image;
        Point x = e.GetPosition(ImageHolder);

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(tmpImg, Canvas.GetLeft(tmpImg) + (x.X - p.X));

            Canvas.SetTop(tmpImg, Canvas.GetTop(tmpImg) + (x.Y - p.Y));
        }
        p = x;
    }

    private void Img_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tmpImg = sender as Image;
        tmpImg.CaptureMouse();
        p = e.GetPosition(ImageHolder);
    }

    private void Img_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tmpImg = sender as Image;
        tmpImg.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I move images around in 3d, under animated control rather than user dragging, but i am pretty sure that the mechanism for moving them would be the same.

first, make just to make sure that the outer canvas isnt getting autosized or something weird like that set it to a fixed width/height.

and with the setting of the position of the images within the Viewport2DVisual3D, I used RenderTransform on the image to set it to its new position.

cheers
Anton